# C言語でのmysqlにおける"mysql_fetch_row"によって得られた"MYSQL_ROW"の値のnullチェック

Tags: mysql, c

C言語にてmysqlを利用しております。

その際、"mysql_fetch_row"によって得られた"MYSQL_ROW row"の値のnullチェックをしたいと考えております。

下記のコードを書いておりますが、"row[1]"の値が無い時に、"if(row[1]!=NULL)"の箇所にてセグメンテーションフォールトになってしまいます。

"if(row[1]!=NULL)"をどのように変更したら良いのでしょうか？

```
    MYSQL *conn;

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *result1;
    char sqlt[256];

    sprintf(sqlt,"SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id=100");
    mysql_query(conn,sqlt);
    result1 = mysql_store_result(conn);
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result1);

    if(row[1]!=NULL){

    }
    mysql_free_result(result1);
```

Comment: フェッチする行がないときはrow自体がNULLになるので row[1]ではダメです。`if (row != NULL)`とするよりは`while(row=mysql_fetch_row(result1)){...}`として存在する行を処理するようにしたほうがいいでしょう

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フェッチする行がないときはrow自体がNULLになるので row[1]ではダメです。

```
if (row != NULL)
```

とするよりは

```
while(row=mysql_fetch_row(result1)){
  // ここに行の処理を書く
}
```

として存在する行を処理するようにしたほうがいいでしょ‌​う